# Angular setPristine doesnt work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to do simple thing, to clean the $scope.user fields and not get the errors because of this.

```
if ($scope.contactForm.$valid) {
    $scope.user = {};
    $scope.contactForm.$setPristine();                   
  }
}
```

But i still see the validations errors like required, and if i dont have any errors he show me all of them.

here is plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/skCdwwTuMVY1fVBNpuQd?p=preview

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: I mean all the errors like required and minlength...

Comment: Ok. I cannot help you without some sample code. Create a jsfiddle that has reproduces your issue and I'll help you.

Comment: i added in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
 $scope.submitted = true;
 if ($scope.contactForm.$valid) {
   $scope.submitted = false;
   $scope.user = {};
   $scope.contactForm.$setPristine();                   
 }
```

The problem with your example is the checkError function is dependent on the submitted flag.  If the form is valid, then you can clear the submitted flag to hide the errors.